# Read configuration parameters from Wildfly system (standalone.xml)

Tags: java, wildfly

I am migrating a web application from Tomcat to Wildfly.

The application was using a configuration file stored under tomcat.

I want to avoid having configuration files and point the application to read these files.

I am looking to have the configuration read from Wildfly system like standalone.xml for instance.

what is the best approach?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please use persistence.xml file in Java app for definition make connection to database from standalone.xml file from WildFly

Excample persistence.xml - connection is get from WildFly. Please add JNDI name java:/PostgresDS in WildFly

```
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
    version="2.1">

    <persistence-unit name="em1">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:/PostgresDS</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />


            </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

Comment: The configuration is for the application is not a DB/JPA setting, it is merely for the application itself.

Comment: I edit my response. Please add <jta-data-source>java:/PostgresDS</jta-data-source> in persistence.xml file

Comment: What was the previous file containing? How was it referenced? You could read in a file from the configuration directory with the file path from the system property for that. Alternatively, just add system properties to the standalone xml - depending on what you are trying to achieve